# Python SimpleHTTPServer doesn't work - A server error occurred

Tags: python, http, localhost, simplehttpserver

I've just tried to run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` in a directory where I have some basic web files. It seems to run fine at first, on the command line it prints:

`Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...`

However, when I try to view my page on `http://127.0.0.1:8000` in browser, I get this error message:

> A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.

Sorry if this seems vague, but I'm not a Python developer so I have no idea why it's not working. Do you have any ideas why or how to start debugging this issue?

Comment: Any message on the command line?

Comment: @PauloBu nothing at all, it just displays the original `Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...`

Comment: Have you tried running it in another port? Test `12345` for example.

Comment: Ah ha! That worked. I had an application open that was running another server on port 8000 that I had forgotten about. If you'd like to add as an answer below, I'll mark it as correct. If not I could delete this question if it's too simple.

Comment: Just delete it :) It was a simple mistake :) Glad I could help! :)

Comment: Although it was upvoted. If you want to keep it I'll add the answer

Comment: Let's add the answer as I guess someone may find it useful. Thanks for spotting!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you aren't seeing anything on the command line, then the server is not getting any input. You must have some other process listening on that port. Try a different port just to be sure:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 12345
```

Just a tip, to check what applications you have listening on which port, `netstat` command can be very useful :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works. What doesn't work is tryng to connect to http://{ip_address}:12345 (or whatever other port) with the browser (Firefox in my case). It simply **can't connect**. (Using just {ip_address} works.)  Does it work for you? If yes, do you have any idea why not for someone else?

Comment: Wow, that's strange. I just tried it out verbatim and it worked with Chrome. Maybe your pc is not letting it bind to 0.0.0.0 (all interfaces). Try it with sudo. Didn't understand the part of "Using just {ip_address} works". What does it mean "works"?

Comment: By "just the IP address" I meant that http://192.168.1.1 (my local IP address) works, so this is not the problem. But http://192.168.1.1:1234 doesn't work. Neither http://0.0.0.0:1234 does, which has no sense and I never saw using it in the examples I found around.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code for Python 3 version:

```
python -m http.server
```